# Trying to read from RSS Feed with Javascript but code does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, rss

I have been trying to get the code below to work but I have had no luck.  I cannot figure out what I"m doing wrong. All I want to do is read the alerts from the link and post them into a list.  I tried two methods but both don't produce any results.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  thank you for your time.

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

FIRST METHOD

<script>
$.get('http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/metro_service_status/feeds/rail_Advisories.xml?',      
     function (data) 
     {
        $(data).find("item").each(function () 
        { 
             var el = $(this);
             console.log("Title");
         });
});
</script>

SECOND METHOD

<script>
$.ajax({ url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/metro_service_status/feeds/rail_Advisories.xml?'),

dataType : 'json',
success  : function (data) {
    if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
    $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
          console.log("Title");
    });
   }
  }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure server responds to you correctly? Add ["error" callback](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and investigate the issue.

Comment: Have you looked at the javascript console? Your request may be blocked due to cross origin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to cross origin nature of the ajax call, use **[jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)** as the data type:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/metro_service_status/feeds/rail_Advisories.xml?'),
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success  : function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseData.feed.entries);  
        $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
            console.log(e.content);
            $(".result").append("<p>" + e.content +  "</p>");
        });
    }    
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/0mw1gs8m/)**

Comment: Thank you so much! =) this is exactly what I was looking for.  I tried to vote up your response but I get a message that says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" not sure what that means.  Thanks again though, you're a life saver ^_^

Comment: sorry to bother you.  I tried accessing one of the tags for this but it does not work. Every time I try to print out <pubDate> I get an "undefined" msg. However the <link> and <title> tags print out correctly. Do you why that could be?  Here is the code I used

    document.write(data.responseData.feed.entries[i].pubDate);
    RESULT: "Undefined"

    document.write(data.responseData.feed.entries[i].title);
    RESULT: Prints out all the titles correctly

Comment: @speedracer2003, the property is publishedDate not pubDate. Here is an updated demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/0mw1gs8m/1/

Comment: Ahhh I see, last question, I promise ^_^  How did you know it was publishedDate and not <pubDate> as it shows in the RSS feed page?  I know that may seem like a dumb question, it's just that I'm really new to this and I want to make sure I understand correctly.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @speedracer2003, in the fiddle i have the line console.log(data.responseData.feed.entries). In Chrome I open the javascript console and inspect the list of entries. Expand any of the 10 entry objects and you will see all its properties.

Comment: Now that the Google Feed API is deprecated, you may consider hosting your own RSS proxy. I open sourced [RSS to API](https://github.com/csm123/RSStoAPI) to provide one that you can easily deploy to Heroku or another host.

Comment: @ezanker Hi there, me again.  I was testing out the Google API link that you provided but it doesn't work now.  I checked the web but I couldn't find anything useful.  Do you by any chance know what may be causing the error?           ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/metro_service_status/feeds/rail_Advisories.xml?'),

Comment: @speedracer2003, looks like google no longer supports that api, the error message is "This API is no longer available."